# angular treeview- get parent node

Tags: angularjs, treeview, parent

I am using  [angular treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview) to build a tree using angularjs. Once I select a node, I want to know the 'parent node' of the selected one.

I don't want to add an attribute named 'parent' in the json data and also don't want to create any array of parent-child key-value pair.
What changes can be done in initial files to get the result?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">

    <div style="display:table-row; width:500px;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; width:250px;">
        <div style="margin:10px 5px 30px 5px; padding:10px; background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:5px; font:12px Tahoma;">
          <span><b>First Tree's Selected Node</b> : <br>{{tree01.currentNode.roleName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; width:250px;">
        <div style="margin:10px 5px 30px 5px; padding:10px; background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:5px; font:12px Tahoma;">
          <span><b>Second Tree's Selected Node</b> : <br>{{tree02.currentNode.roleName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row; width:500px;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; width:250px;">

        <!-- FIRST TREE -->
        <div data-angular-treeview="true" data-tree-id="tree01" data-tree-model="roleList1" data-node-id="roleId" data-node-label="roleName" data-node-children="children">
        </div>


      </div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; width:250px;">

        <!-- SECOND TREE -->
        <div data-angular-treeview="true" data-tree-id="tree02" data-tree-model="roleList2" data-node-id="roleId" data-node-label="roleName" data-node-children="children">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/b9Pnw/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these changes.

**In Markup:** (add ng-click attribute)

```
 <div
    data-angular-treeview="true"
    data-tree-id="tree01"
    data-tree-model="roleList1"
    data-node-id="roleId"
    data-node-label="roleName"
    data-node-children="children" 
    ng-click="printParent($event);">
</div>
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.printParent = function ($event) {
  var root = $scope;
  var currentScope = angular.element($event.target).scope();
  console.log('selected Node details: ', currentScope.node);
  currentScope = currentScope.$parent;
  console.log('parents::')
  while(currentScope.$id !== root.$id) {
    console.log(currentScope.node);
    currentScope = currentScope.$parent;
  }
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9Pnw/131/)

To access the parent in the directive:

**Click Handler**

```
scope[treeId].selectNodeLabel = 
    function( selectedNode, selectedNodeScope ){
        if (selectedNodeScope) {
            var parentScope = selectedNodeScope.$parent,
                index,
                targetArray;
            if (parentScope.node) {
                targetArray = parentScope.node.children;
            } else {
                //root node
                targetArray = scope[treeModel];
            }
            // to insert after the index;
            if (targetArray.length) {
                index = targetArray.indexOf(selectedNode);
                console.log('index :: ', index, 'parent::', targetArray);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    //targetArray.splice(index, 0, newNodeToBeAdded)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

**In Directive template**

```
<span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeLabel(node, this)">{{node.' + nodeLabel + '}}</span>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3d4p6ez/3/)

Comment: thank you @Vinay k for your edit and answer. my purpose of getting the parent node was to add a node as a sibling of current selected node.. As your method is written in main controller, m not able to access the parent inside the directive.

Comment: In which directive you want to access the parent? Please update your plnkr with your expectations.

Comment: can we have access to the parent in the 'selectNodeLabel()' method of this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j3d4p6ez/2/) . As m trying to add a node, it gets added to a different scope and not dynamically rendered in the tree.

Comment: @vedants, I have updated the fiddle and the answer, please check it.

Comment: u saved some crucial couple of hours... i must buy you a cup of starbucks coffee

Comment: @Kings glad to help you. Will be waiting for the coffee.. :)

Comment: @VinayK - thanks for the solution I was looking for days.  Is there any way to push the result printed in console to an array or something.

I want to show breadcrumbs when node is selected, for eg: if i select node subuser2-1-1 then i want User->subUser2->subuser2-1->subuser2-1-1

Comment: Is there any way to expand the folder view, if there is a single node without child node ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print parent like this.In MarkUp

```
 <div
    data-angular-treeview="true"
    data-tree-id="tree01"
    data-tree-model="roleList1"
    data-node-id="roleId"
    data-node-label="roleName"
    data-node-children="children" 
    ng-click="printParent(this)">
 </div>
```

In Controller

```
 $scope.printParent = function(item) {
   var parent = item.$modelValue;
   Console.log(parent);
 };
```